# Is there a modifier that can dissolve edge loops?

Tags: modifiers, loop

I'm willing to use add-ons if any exist. It's very important to maintain a fully quad mesh, so dissolving edge loops to decimate is the cleanest way to finalize the asset. A modifier that can do this would really help with this workflow, simply targeting edge loops in areas where polygons are more dense, or else at points where the average angles between each edge loop are small enough using a slider similar to planar decimation.

Comment: In the Decimate modifier there is an Un-Subdivide function.

Comment: note that the *Un-Subdivide* function only supports grid topology ([T65748](https://developer.blender.org/T65748)). If there are 3-star or 5-star poles, the result will have defects.

Comment: Un-subdivide just completely affects a mesh, this is not an answer. Un-subdivide is not the same as targeting and dissolving edge loops at low angles, which is a method that results in an asset that is lower poly but often indistinguishable from the original.

Comment: Hi :). Since you mentioned 'dissolving loops at low angles' may i suggest the Decimate modifier :))

Answer (score 0):

You can sort-of do that with the weld modifier.

It acts as the "merge by distance" operator : it will merge vertices within a specified distance. And the modifier allows you to use vertex groups to target specific parts of your mesh.

[image: demo picture]